# Switching ASP.Net Web API returns between XML and JSON; where's it done?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have an [ASP.Net Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api) project. In my controller is this simple 'boiler plate' API method:

```
using System.Web.Http;
public class DataController : ApiController
{
    private static Random _Random = new Random();

    [Route("api/getrandomdoubles/{count:int}")]
    [AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]
    public double[] GetRandomDoubles(int count)
    {
        var doubles = new double[count];
        for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            doubles[i] = _Random.NextDouble();
        }
        return doubles;
    }
}
```

(N.B. I've cut out the other methods.)

If I call this in the browser thus `http://localhost:1165/api/GetRandomDoubles/2` I get XML returned:

```
<ArrayOfdouble xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
    <double>0.3777879822895806</double>
    <double>0.46401416811347668</double>
</ArrayOfdouble>
```

And if I call it from JavaScript thus:

```
d3.json('api/getrandomdoubles/2', function (error, data) {
    //Do stuff
});
```

I get back JSON `[0.6679551008473873,0.9205140638726363]`.

What is deciding when my controller API method returns XML and when it returns JSON? I'm guessing it is decided based on the HTTP verb, i.e. `PUT` or `GET` but I cannot see where that is specified. How would I control the return type myself?

========== EDIT ==========

I have just realised that this is browser specific. Calling `http://localhost:1165/api/GetRandomDoubles/2` in IE returns JSON, calling it in Chrome returns XML.

Answer (score 3):

It is called as [Content Negotiation](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/content-negotiation) in Web API.

First, the pipeline gets the IContentNegotiator service from the HttpConfiguration object. It also gets the list of media formatters from the HttpConfiguration.Formatters collection.

Next, the pipeline calls IContentNegotiatior.Negotiate, passing in:

1. The type of object to serialize
2. The collection of media formatters
3. The HTTP request

The Negotiate method returns two pieces of information:

1. Which formatter to use
2. The media type for the response

If no formatter is found, the Negotiate method returns null, and the client recevies HTTP error 406 (Not Acceptable).